# Minecraft EXCEPTION ACCESS VIOLATION

Tags: windows-8, drivers, java, minecraft

When I run any version of Minecraft, I receive an error `EXCEPTION ACCESS VIOLATION`. It occurs usually on the mojang screen but it also happens in game if I get past this point. Interestingly, I can play for much longer on vanilla than I can on tekkit. Here is some extra information as well as the error log.

**PC Specs:**

- 8GB DDR3 1333mhz RAM
- Intel i3 4330 3.5ghz Duel Core
- Palit GTX 770 jetstream
- Gigabyte GA-H81M-D2V
- Windows 8 64bit

**Things Tried:**

- Turning AdvancedOpenGL off
- Updating/ Reinstalling Java
- Reinstalling Minecraft
- Updating GPU Drivers (Already up-to-date)
- Updating other drivers
- Updating DirectX
- Different versions of MC (Tried: Tekkit Classic, FTB Unleashed, Vanilla 1.7.9, Vanilla 1.8 Snapshot, Yogscast Complete Pack (ATLauncher), Attack of the B Team) - None work

**Error Logs (for modded):**

Full error log found [here](http://pastebin.com/jwU2KMme) since I could not fit it all in to the body!

I have had this problem for around 3 weeks and have still found no solution so any help is massively appreciated.

**Update DxDiag:**

The following is the request from @Ramhound.

```
Card name: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 770
       Manufacturer: NVIDIA
          Chip type: GeForce GTX 770
           DAC type: Integrated RAMDAC
        Device Type: Full Device
         Device Key: Enum\PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_1184&SUBSYS_11841569&REV_A1
     Display Memory: 4034 MB
   Dedicated Memory: 1986 MB
      Shared Memory: 2048 MB
       Current Mode: 1920 x 1080 (32 bit) (60Hz)
       Monitor Name: AOC 2343
      Monitor Model: 2343
         Monitor Id: AOC2343
        Native Mode: 1920 x 1080(p) (60.000Hz)
        Output Type: DVI
        Driver Name: nvd3dumx.dll,nvwgf2umx.dll,nvwgf2umx.dll,nvd3dum,nvwgf2um,nvwgf2um
Driver File Version: 9.18.0013.3523 (English)
     Driver Version: 9.18.13.3523
        DDI Version: 11
     Feature Levels: 11.0,10.1,10.0,9.3,9.2,9.1
       Driver Model: WDDM 1.2
Graphics Preemption: DMA
 Compute Preemption: DMA
  Driver Attributes: Final Retail
   Driver Date/Size: 3/4/2014 15:35:23, 17755424 bytes
        WHQL Logo'd: Yes
    WHQL Date Stamp: 
  Device Identifier: {D7B71E3E-52C4-11CF-1A7B-89311CC2C435}
```

**Update Current Status:**

Well, after doing more trawling through what must be hundreds of internet *solutions* (I use the word loosely) I have still got no further. It would appear there are very few questions or other people who have `jvm.dll` (the Java Virtual machine) as their problematic frame. The majority are Intel Series 4 Drivers or ATI OpenAL, none of which are mentioned in my error reports. As suggested in the comments, I have tried downgrading to Java 7 Build 55, Java 7 Build 45, Java 6 Build 45 and back up to Java 8 Build 5. None of this has helped although on the reinstall of Java 8 I was able to play Minecraft for a whole hour! My god it was fun! But anyway...

**Nearly a month later...:**

Well, a month later and with still no definitive answer and still no solution found by myself, I guess I'll update here again (It's better than a new question) Anyway so yeah, I am currently <s>able to play vanilla although it does crash sometimes</s> **update:** It crashes all the time. For some reason this has got worse. I am only able to play Modded Minecraft **after** having restarted my PC, and even then I can only play for around 10 - 20 minutes before it stops and I have to restart again. I have also tried to copy the Java program files from the `Program Files` directory on a laptop running the same OS as me. That didn't help. I also changed the permissions on the `jre7` folder to Read  & Write, but that didn't help either. (I also reverted these two changed after I tested them as a realise they are both kind-of holes in my security.) So there you go, a month on an I am still plagued by the words that have become the bane of my once minecraft but now `EXCEPTION ACCESS VIOLATION` filled life. Again, any help you can give will help massively.

Comment: Have you tried **downgrading** Java? I know it's a bit of a security risk but that might resolve the problem.

Comment: I just downgraded from Java 8 5 to Java 7 55 which didn't help. Downgraded further from 7 55 to Java 7 45. This gave a fatal error that the VM couldn't be created. (I deleted the other Java versions when I installed a new one)

Comment: Post the information from dxdiag.  I want to see the version of the driver your using for myself.

Comment: @Ramhound I have added the Driver info. However, I tried to save all of DxDiag's information to desktop and it was huge so I will amend with any information I missed since I just picked the driver related things.